# R [Dplyr]: Adding column after applying Summary function

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble, summarize

I hope you are able to advise in how effectively use the `dplyr` package.

I have a `data.frame` with three columns, country, company name and satisfaction score.

Ultimately, I would like to find the nth company for every country based on satisfaction indicator.

So far, I have done the following:

```
ordered_needed_data_ha %>% group_by(Country) %>% summarise(value = nth(`Satisfaction Score`, 10, order_by = Country))
#This gives me the 10th highest satisfaction score in the given country.
```

This evaluates to, after piping `head()`

```
Country value
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 AL     NA  
 2 AT     15.7
 3 BG     17.1
 4 FR     14.9
 5 IT     13.3
```

How could I add the company name with the given value for the country ?
Adding an additional grouping argument does not work, like `group_by(Country, Company)`

So the desired outcome would be something like:

```
Country Company value
   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
 1 AL     CompanyX NA 
 2 AT     CompanyX 15.7
 3 BG     CompanyX 17.1
 4 FR     CompanyX 14.9
 5 IT     CompanyX 13.3
```

I am not a regular R user, I would appreciate your help. Thanks !

Comment: Could you post a sample of `ordered_needed_data_ha`? You might be able to retain the company name in your `summarize` statement with something like `summarize(..., Company = unique(Company))`.

Comment: FYI, you are grouping by `Country` in your code, the `order_by=Country` is likely doing nothing since the `nth`-calculation is only taking into account one country's scores at a time.

Comment: Oh yes, apologies. The ```order_by``` is dispensable. As the order is already in the original data.frame. I cannot disclose the company names, but there is a one to many relationship between country and company. Sometimes not every country has the nth value. For example. For Albania there are only eight companies with a satisfaction score.

Comment: Note that `nth(x, n)` just takes the `n`-th value of `x`. It does not sort `x` by default. If you want the `n`-th value after sorting ascendingly, you should use `nth(x, n, order_by = x)`, or arrange the data and then `slice(n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the use of `summarize` is not necessary. I think you're effectively just doing a `slice` operation.

For instance, mimicking your code:

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(value = nth(disp, 2))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#     cyl value
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4  147.
# 2     6  160 
# 3     8  360
```

We can get the same rows (note the identical `disp` values) and as much of the remaining columns using `slice`:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  slice(2) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 × 11
#     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
# 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
# 3  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
```

If you really want to continue using `summarize` (for unseen reasons, perhaps), then you can use `nth` still:

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(value = nth(disp, 2), value2 = nth(hp, 2))
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#     cyl value value2
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     4  147.     62
# 2     6  160     110
# 3     8  360     245
```

or with multiple columns and `across`, a little more robust perhaps?

```r
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(across(c(disp, hp), ~ nth(., 2)))
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#     cyl  disp    hp
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4  147.    62
# 2     6  160    110
# 3     8  360    245
```

Comment: Yes,  that has helped. Using ```slice``` and ```ungroup```, I also have re-ordered the columns so that they display country, company, satisfaction score. Just as in your example the ungrouping of cyl, evaluates to have it as it the second, not the first column. Thank you very much for your help !!